# 'implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0' gives Could not get resource ERROR

Tags: android, gradle, android-recyclerview

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 & in my android project
I'm trying to add

```
'implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

After sync it gives me following errors and I'm not getting what's wrong.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration

```
':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not determine artifacts for com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0
Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/28.0.0/recyclerview-v7-28.0.0.aar'.
Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/28.0.0/recyclerview-v7-28.0.0.aar'.
Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Other information :

```
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}


buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: why don't you use androidX?

Comment: But why this is not working? Can you give me the solution?

Comment: please add your `build.gradle(Project:projectname)` code

Comment: I've already added into Other "information section". Please check. Thank you

Comment: try adding `maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }` after `jcenter()`

Comment: Just added this but still those errors are there :(

Comment: try using a vpn and then sync gradle files

Comment: VPN? Why? I mean is google limiting their services to certain countries?

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines from your build.gradle and try to sync it again, may be these lines are causing issue.

```
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'll surely try it.